# Creating a tree in JavaScript with nested Promises containing loops

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I've been trying to figure out how to solve this problem but failed. Basically I'm building a tree of data with the following structure:

```
tree = [
  {
    'title': 'Company 1',
    'children': [
      {
        'title': 'Opportunity 1',
        'children': [
          {
            'title': 'Library 1'
          },  // library
          {
            'title': 'Library 2'
          }  // library
         ]
       },  // opportunity
       {
         'title': 'Opportunity 2',
         'children': [
           {
             'title': 'Library 1'
           },  // library
           {
             'title': 'Library 2'
           }  // library
         ]
       },  // opportunity
     ]
  },  // client
 ... 
]
```

I have written the following code <s>which fills up the tree nodes fine</s>, I just do not know how to find out when the filling process has finished and the tree is ready to use.

Do you have any ideas how to handle this?

```
  getList(getGetSitesURL(site)).then(r => {
    r.d.results.map(site => {
      var client = {};
      client['title'] = site.Title;

      getList(getGetSitesURL(site.ServerRelativeUrl)).then(r => {
        r.d.results.map(site => {
          var opportunity = {};
          var opportunities = [];
          opportunity['title'] = site.Title;

          getLibrary(getGetLibrariesURL(site.ServerRelativeUrl)).then(r => {
            r.d.results.map(lib => {
              var library = {};
              var libraries = [];
              library['title'] = lib.Title;
              libraries.push(library);

              opportunity['children'] = libraries;
              opportunities.push(opportunity);
              client['children'] = opportunities;
              tree.push(client);
            })
          })
        });
      })
    })
  })
```

EDIT: I have just found out this solution **does not work** as intended and I end up having duplicates in the tree array. Perhaps someone could tell me how to handle this problem in a different way. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `Promise.all`?

Comment: I have, but didn't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Every of your `function`s needs to return a promise. Please show your attempt

Comment: It does return a promise, I'm using fetch to make the calls.

Comment: No, none of your `function` callbacks in the code you've shown `return` *anything*.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were asking about returns of the functions getList and getLibrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues:

- You are pushing `client` objects at the deepest level of your iterations, which means you will in general get too many of them.
- When you use `map`, you should use it as an alternative to `push`, since that returns an array, making `push` unnecessary and leading to more functional code.
- `libraries` gets reset to `[]` in each `map` iteration: this cannot be right and will every time lead to an array with just one element, where you would need to get as many elements as `map` is iterating.
- Instead of mutating your data structure, use functional code that returns the promises so that eventually you get the complete tree as the promised value and can process it in a final `then` callback.

Here is an implementation that should work:

```
getList(getGetSitesURL(site)).then(r =>
    Promise.all(r.d.results.map(site => 
        getList(getGetSitesURL(site.ServerRelativeUrl)).then( r =>
            Promise.all(r.d.results.map(subsite => 
                getLibrary(getGetLibrariesURL(subsite.ServerRelativeUrl)).then(r => ({ 
                    title: subsite.Title, 
                    children: r.d.results.map(lib => ({ title: lib.Title }))
                }))
            )).then(children => ({ title: site.Title, children}))
        )
    ))
).then(tree => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(tree, null, 2));
});
```

The output would be something like:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Company1",
    "children": [
      {
        "title": "Opportunity 1",
        "children": [
          {
            "title": "Library 1"
          },
          {
            "title": "Library 2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "Opportunity 1",
        "children": [
          {
            "title": "Library 1"
          },
          {
            "title": "Library 2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

#### Returning promises

Please note that the above code uses arrow functions with the expression syntax as opposed to the statement block syntax (so there is no brace after the fat arrow `=>`). That expression following the fat arrow is evaluated as the *return* value of such arrow function. To do the same thing using a statement block syntax you would change `=> expression` to `=> { return expression; }`.

Comment: Thank you very much @trincot, it works fine. There is only one problem though, the libraries are pulled from the top level sites, not from subsites. What I would like is to get libraries for each of these: getList(getGetSitesURL(site.ServerRelativeUrl)).

Comment: Ah yes, I see... let me check that.

Comment: I was trying to fix it myself but again have no idea how to achieve this without using another nested map function. My JavaScript skills are not very good at the moment. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thanks @trincot, you saved me there!

Comment: So, you don't explain at all that by switching to arrow functions, you are implicitly returning promises from `Promise.all()` inside your `.then()` handlers.  You've missed the opportunity to explain/teach a huge part of why this works and what has to be done to solve the main issue in the OP's question.  Many newbies will miss that concept entirely.

Comment: @jfriend00, indeed the fact that promises are *returned* by the callback functions is important. I mentioned this in my bullet list, but have now also added a paragraph on the short form of the arrow syntax. Thanks for having highlighted this.

Answer (score 0):

If you return promises from within your `.then()` handlers, then those promises will get added to the chain and you can tell when things are done by monitoring the top level promise.  In addition, anywhere you are creating multiple promises in one scope, you can monitor when all of them are done with `Promise.all()` and return that one master promise.

Here's how that would work in the code you showed.  Summary of changes:

1. Anywhere you run `.map()` and create multiple promises, use `Promise.all()` on the resulting array of promises to know when they are all done.
2. Inside your `.map()` callback, return the promise you create so that the result of the `.map()` will be an array of promises you can then use `Promise.all()` with.
3. Inside every `.then()` handler that runs any async operation, return a promise that monitors that async operation(s) so it will then be chained to the parent promise.
4. Use a `.then()` on the top level promise to know when all the chained internal promises are indeed done.

Here's how this could be applied to the code you show.

```
getList(getGetSitesURL(site)).then(r => {
    // Use Promise.all() to know when the array of promises are all done
    return Promise.all(r.d.results.map(site => {
        var client = {};
        client['title'] = site.Title;

        // return this promise so .map() results in an array of promises
        return getList(getGetSitesURL(site.ServerRelativeUrl)).then(r => {
            // Use Promise.all() to know when the array of promises are all done
            return Promise.all(r.d.results.map(site => {
                var opportunity = {};
                var opportunities = [];
                opportunity['title'] = site.Title;

                // return this promise so .map() results in an array of promises
                return getLibrary(getGetLibrariesURL(site.ServerRelativeUrl)).then(r => {
                    r.d.results.map(lib => {
                        var library = {};
                        var libraries = [];
                        library['title'] = lib.Title;
                        libraries.push(library);

                        opportunity['children'] = libraries;
                        opportunities.push(opportunity);
                        client['children'] = opportunities;
                        tree.push(client);
                    });
                });
            }));
        });
    }));
}).then(function() {
    // all done here
}).catch(function(err) {
    // some error here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for help, although I realised my approach is all wrong and the nested map functions generate a lot of duplicates.

Comment: @lukas - Well, I answered the question that was in front of my at the time until you changed it.  I also explained the concept of returning promises from within `.then()` handlers to chain promises together so you can figure out when the whole thing is done (something the other answer does not explain at all).  Glad you got an eventual answer.